# Lightweight 3D Python library

Tags: library, python, 3d, game-development

I've been working on a personal Python project and I need some simple 3D graphics. I know about Panda3D, but all I really need is:

- Wireframe graphics
- Hidden surface removal (one step up from wireframe)
- Camera control
- Bonus feature: Color control (different colored lines)

What I don't need:

- Textures
- Lighting
- Pretty much everything else a full 3D engine provides

To be honest, I don't need anything more sophisticated than this:

[image]

I use Pygame, and it's a nice 2D graphics and game library, but it doesn't have any support for 3D. Panda3D is a 3D library, but it's overkill for what I need. I considered writing my own library, but figured that someone must've already done it (possibly using Pygame). Is there such a Python library, or do I have to "roll my own"?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found what I need. I found this tutorial on the YouTube:
[How to program 3D graphics from scratch. Without 3D engines. (In Python)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4E9iq0BixA)

The author walks through making a 3D engine from scratch using the Pygame library. Fairly simple and straightforward engine, I think it has everything I need.

I've been following it, but have run into some bugs. Fingers crossed that I'll resolve them!